# Hide PivotChart columns

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table

Is there any way to hide or show certain columns in a PivotTable? For example I have two columns displaying the average sales and the sum of all sales for the months in a year. Is there any way I can pick one of those two when making a chart without duplicating the pivot table or deleting one of those two values?

Example table:

```
m/f  apples  pears melons        
jan   20       30   40
feb   10       20   10
mar    5       6    12
```

For example, I want to see a chart displaying only the `apples` and `melons`, filtering out the `pears` without losing the ability to easily compare `apples` and `pears` afterwards.

Comment: Is that what your pivot table output looks like, or the source data?

Comment: That's what the pivot table looks like

Comment: I'm not making this for myself so it should be pretty user friendly and fool proof. I don't want the user to manually have to change the series color each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For user friendly and fool proof the down arrow next to the Column Labels entry at the head of the PivotTable should suit:

[image: SO25745523 example]

Comment: in where I am. Thanks!